# Arrange listView or recyclerView items like chipGroup

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, android-recyclerview

I have some tags (Array of String), when I use a recyclerView or listView it only accept Vertical, Horizontal or Grid arrangements, but I need to implement it like chip group lazy arrangement, how do I do that,

Like this
[chipGroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAflY.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [Google's `flexbox-layout` library](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) for this. It provides a [`FlexboxLayoutManager` for use with `RecyclerView`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview):

```
val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(context).apply {
    setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW)
}

context.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview).setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```